# Create List of Words that Appear In String Without Spaces - Account For When Word Appears More Than Once

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, word-frequency

As per [this Codewars challenge](https://www.codewars.com/kata/new-cashier-does-not-know-about-space-or-shift/train/javascript), I need to create some simple logic for keeping track of all of the words that appear in a string.

---

**INSTRUCTIONS**

Some new cashiers started to work at your restaurant.

They are good at taking orders, but they don't know how to capitalize words, or use a space bar!

All the orders they create look something like this:

"milkshakepizzachickenfriescokeburgerpizzasandwichmilkshakepizza"

The kitchen staff are threatening to quit, because of how difficult it is to read the orders.

Their preference is to get the orders as a nice clean string with spaces and capitals like so:

"Burger Fries Chicken Pizza Pizza Pizza Sandwich Milkshake Milkshake Coke"

The kitchen staff expect the items to be in the same order as they appear in the menu.

The menu items are fairly simple, there is no overlap in the names of the items:

1. Burger
2. Fries
3. Chicken
4. Pizza
5. Sandwich
6. Onionrings
7. Milkshake
8. Coke

---

**EDIT** Following the `.match()` logic, I've created an array of *all* items that appear in the input. But I don't know the quickest way to sort them according to their order of appearance in the original string:

```js
function getOrder(order) {
  
  let menu = ['Burger', 'Fries', 'Chicken', 'Pizza', 'Sandwich', 'Onionrings', 'Milkshake', 'Coke'];
  
  let finalOrder = order.split(/(burger|fries|chicken|pizza|sandwich|onionrings|milkshake|coke)/i);
  finalOrder = finalOrder.filter((element) => element !== null || element !== "");
  finalOrder = finalOrder.map((element) => element.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + element.slice(1));
  finalOrder = finalOrder.sort((a, b) => {
    if (menu.indexOf(a) > menu.indexOf(b)) {
      return 1;
    }
    else {
      return -1;
    }
  });
  return finalOrder.join(" ").trim(/\s/);
}

console.log(getOrder("milkshakepizzachickenfriescokeburgerpizzasandwichmilkshakepizza"));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create an array of all matching items that exist within the input string
2. Turn the first letter of all items in the array to Uppercase, so that they match the items in the menu array exactly.
3. Sort the items according to their order in the menu array.
4. Return the array joined into a string.

```js
function getOrder(input) {
    
  let menu = ['Burger','Fries','Chicken','Pizza','Sandwich','Onionrings','Milkshake','Coke'];
  let items = input.match(/(burger|fries|chicken|pizza|sandwich|onionrings|milkshake|coke)/gi);
  items = items.map((element) => element.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + element.slice(1));
  items = items.sort((a, b) => {
    if (menu.indexOf(a) > menu.indexOf(b)) {
      return 1;
    }
    else {
      return -1;
    }
  });
  return items.join(" ");
}

console.log(getOrder("milkshakepizzachickenfriescokeburgerpizzasandwichmilkshakepizza"));
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `includes` use `indexOf`. That takes a second parameter, the index to start searching. Loop over all burgers for example, and pass the previous index to the next `indexOf` call, until it returns -1, then count how often you've looped.

Alternatively, you can `.match` the text based on a regex that accepts all possible dishes.

Comment: Btw, my solution is 56 chars long.

Comment: Can you please explain the `.match` technique that would accept all possible dishes from a regex?

Comment: NVM I'm figuring it out - one second!

Comment: If you take a look at my edit above, I've created a string that includes all items from the original order, but they are not in the order in which they originally appear. Next step.

Comment: Hint: You just need one regex.

Comment: Yeah I discovered `order.split(/(burger|fries|chicken|pizza|sandwich|onionrings|milkshake|coke)/i);`. Unfortunately that works in my console but still causes a timeout error on Codewars.

Comment: Don't split. Match.

Comment: Got it - answer below. This way is the most simple and straightforward, IMO.

Comment: I dont think that we should document solutions for coding challenges on a public site (although this is a very simple kata)

Answer (score 2):

Here is my solution to that challenge:

**Explanation:**

For each menu item: Count the number of occurrences of the item and add the item to the output string that many times.

- `RegExp(i, 'gi')`: Case **i**nsensitive **g**lobal match for counting
- `|| []`: Handle matching 0 times
- `.length`: Only get the **count** of matches
- `Array().fill(i)`: Create sized array filled with the menu item, repeated
- `...`: Expand array so push inserts elements individually in the array
- `.join(' ')`: Finally, insert spaces between each match

**Example:**

```js
let menu = ['Burger','Fries','Chicken','Pizza','Sandwich','Onionrings','Milkshake','Coke'];

function getOrder(input) {
  let output = [];
  menu.forEach( (i) =>
    output.push( ...Array( (input.match( RegExp(i, 'gi') ) || []).length ).fill( i ) )
  );
  return output.join(' ');
}

console.log( getOrder("milkshakepizzachickenfriescokeburgerpizzasandwichmilkshakepizza") )
```

Answer (score 1):

If you knew *where* in the string your word was, you could remove it, so that if you looked again in the remaining string, you'd find the duplicate.

Comment: Thx, let me try that

Answer (score 1):

You can also iterate character by character and append words as they form. To check if a word is "formed", you can use a set to store the words/menu-items that are valid:

```js
function getOrder(input) {

  let order = [];
  const items = new Set(["burger", "fries", "chicken", "pizza", "sandwich", "onionrings", "milkshake", "coke"]);

  let curr = "";
  for (let c of [...input]) {
    curr += c;
    if (items.has(curr)) {
      order.push(curr);
      curr = "";
    }
  }
  return order.map(item => item.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + item.slice(1)).join(" ");
}

console.log(getOrder("milkshakepizzachickenfriescokeburgerpizzasandwichmilkshakepizza"));
```

Comment: It isn't mentioned in the question, (only in the codewars challenge) but the output order should match the order of the menu items.

Answer (score 1):

Create an array containing the menu items in lower case in the order given

```
let testString = "milkshakepizzachickenfriescokeburgerpizzasandwichmilkshakepizza";
let menuItemsLowerCase = ["burger","fries","chicken","pizza","sandwich","onionrings","milkshake","coke"];
```

Iterate over each item and replace the occurrence of each item with the item string plus a comma

```
for(let itemIndex=0;itemIndex<menuItemsLowerCase.length; itemIndex++){
    const item = menuItemsLowerCase[itemIndex];
    const re = new RegExp(item,"g");
    testString = testString.replace(re, item+',');
}
```

Remove the last comma if any

```
if(testString[testString.length-1] === ','){
    testString = testString.substr(0,testString.length-1);
}
```

Split the string onto commas and sort

```
let stringAsArray = testString.split(',');
stringAsArray = stringAsArray.sort(function(a,b){
    return menuItemsLowerCase.indexOf(a) - menuItemsLowerCase.indexOf(b);
});
```

Convert first character to upper case and join back with space as the separator

```
console.log(stringAsArray.map(function(item){
        return item.substr(0,1).toUpperCase() + item.substr(1);
    }
).join(' '));
```